# Are $L^{1}(\mathbb{R)}$ and $L^{1}((0,1))$ isometric?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Can I find an isometric isomorphism between $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^{1}((0,1))$, where both spaces are defined using the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093538/lp-mathbbr-is-isomterically-isomorphic-to-lp0-1?rq=1 There's an answer in a comment.

Comment: @Yanko OK thank you so much! It seems to work.